# Move div with fixed position if window size changes

Tags: javascript, html, css, markup

How can i do the following:
I need a div to change it's position when the page is opened on a narrow screen or browser window size is changed.
The fixed div should stay on the same vertical position when the page is scrolled up or down, but i also need it to be lets say 10px away from the largest div(a container for smaller divs, see the picture please). Now when i resize the window the fixed div comes over the div to the right.

So the question is how can i make this fixed div stay on the same position when scrolling the page vertically and make it always be 10px away from the right div? Css class for fixed is:

```
.fixed{
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:100px;
    left:100px;
    text-indent:-9999px;
}
```

In fact i'm trying to implement a "back to top" button, so the fixed div is this button and the largest div is page's content.

Here is what i have now:

[image]

Comment: You can try changing the position of the container div itself.

Comment: Position the right div relatively to the small div

Comment: @harsha
I can't move the container div because it's page's content and it is always centered

Comment: Well , If your window size is smaller than the size of the container div ?

Comment: @harsha
then a horizontal scrollbar should appear

Comment: @innocent_rifle let me know if you need a hand with the below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your css to make it look like this:

```
.fixed{
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:100px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -[(maincontainerwidth/2) + 50];
    text-indent:-9999px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two ways I would do it:

1) custom javascript that reads the width of window and changes your css

2) or using a library like adapt.js to detect and swap between .css

Key term: [Responsive Web Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)

Take a look at [adapt.js](http://adapt.960.gs/) its a javascript library that will load different css files based on page window size. This technique is great if you want to display things different between lets say mobile and desktop screen.

In your scenario this would potentially work also.

**1) Reference adapt.js**

```
<script src="/js/adapt.js" type="text/javascript></script>
```

**2) Configure**

So essentially you'd have two views:

```
// Edit to suit your needs.
var ADAPT_CONFIG = {
  // Where is your CSS?
  path: 'assets/css/',

  // false = Only run once, when page first loads.
  // true = Change on window resize and page tilt.
  dynamic: true,

  // Optional callback... myCallback(i, width)
  callback: myCallback,

  // First range entry is the minimum.
  // Last range entry is the maximum.
  // Separate ranges by "to" keyword.
  range: [
    '0px    to 760px  = Narrow.css', // css for narrow views
    '760px  to 980px  = Narrow.css',
    '980px  to 1280px = Wide.css', // css for wide views
    '1280px to 1600px = Wide.css',
    '1600px to 1920px = Wide.css',
    '1940px to 2540px = Wide.css',
    '2540px           = Wide.css'
  ]
};
```

**3) Altogether would look like**

```
<html>
    <head>
    ...

    <script src="/js/adapt.js" type="text/javascript></script>
    <script type="text/javascript>
        // Edit to suit your needs.
        var ADAPT_CONFIG = {
          // Where is your CSS?
          path: 'assets/css/',

          // false = Only run once, when page first loads.
          // true = Change on window resize and page tilt.
          dynamic: true,

          // Optional callback... myCallback(i, width)
          callback: myCallback,

          // First range entry is the minimum.
          // Last range entry is the maximum.
          // Separate ranges by "to" keyword.
          range: [
            '0px    to 760px  = Narrow.css', // css for narrow views
            '760px  to 980px  = Narrow.css',
            '980px  to 1280px = Wide.css', // css for wide views
            '1280px to 1600px = Wide.css',
            '1600px to 1920px = Wide.css',
            '1940px to 2540px = Wide.css',
            '2540px           = Wide.css'
          ]
        };
    </script>
    ...
    </head>
    <body>
            ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can do all this with media queries.

Comment: @ClaytonMisura yes but css3 was not specified. So I went with a solution that wouldn't need html5/css3

Answer (score 0):

#### Wrapper!

I guess the best way to control this is by using a wrapper `div`. So, have something like this:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <!-- Contents -->
    <div class="fixed">
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Now add with the CSS:

```
.wrap {width: [fixed width]; position: relative;}
.fixed {left: -100px;}
```

I feel the wrapper `div` is not necessary as the `body` itself is `relative`ly `position`ed. Using this method, the `div` stays in the same position.